# Using apache.commons.math library for java "cannot find symbol" error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, apache-commons

I'm trying to use the [apache library](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/analysis.html) to solve a polynomial equation. I'm not a java pro so, I've likely made a stupid mistake. That's why this code doesn't work:

```
import org.apache.commons.math.analysis.*;
import org.apache.commons.math.analysis.solvers.*;
import org.apache.commons.math.analysis.polynomials.*;
import org.apache.commons.math.analysis.LaguerreSolver.*;

double rp = 1, M=10000, Mp = 500; 
double rrp = rp*rp, rp2 = 2.0*rp; // shorthand variables for powers of rp
double[] c = { -rrp*rrp, rp2*rrp, -(Mp/M+1)*rrp, rrp, rp2, 1.0 };

PolynomialFunction lagrangian = new PolynomialFunction(c);
LaguerreSolver solver = new LaguerreSolver();
double rs = solver.solve(100, lagrangian, rp, 2*rp);
System.out.println("rs: "+rs);
```

Fails with this message:

```
/home/confus/Desktop/EJS_4.3.3.1/workspace/output/lagrange_pkg/lagrange.java:334: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method solve(int,org.apache.commons.math.analysis.polynomials.PolynomialFunction,double,double)
location: class org.apache.commons.math.analysis.solvers.LaguerreSolver
    double rs = solver.solve(100, lagrangian, rp, 2*rp);  // > Initialization.Init Page:18
                  ^
1 error
```

I'd appreciate your help. Where's the error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of the API?  The 2.0 API does not have a solve method with the signature you're using.  The 3.0 snapshot does, but maybe you're linking against the wrong JAR?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [javadoc for solve](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/analysis/solvers/LaguerreSolver.html#solve%28int,%20org.apache.commons.math.analysis.UnivariateRealFunction,%20double,%20double%29), it accepts [UnivariateRealFunction](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/analysis/UnivariateRealFunction.html)s of which PolynomialFunction is a subclass, so your syntax is correct. I expect you are using an old version of the commons math library. Check that you are using the latest commons math implementation (2.2) and that no old versions are on your class path.

Comment: okay, I will check on that. If I do something like `UnivariateRealFunction lagrangian = new PolynomialFunction(c);` could that work? Also is there a way to include all classes and sublasses of `org.apache.commons.math.analysis` so I don't have to use four import statements?

Comment: Your imports are already as concise as they can be.  Get your version straight - use doc for the same version you're running - if you don't you'll continue to have problems like this.  If you don't know what version it is, download a known one, or, look in the MANIFEST.MF in the jar (but it may not be there).  There are other versions in the MANIFEST.MF - don't get confused.  It should be "Implementation-Version" and-or "Specification-Version".

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create a class in your .java file - it's not valid Java.  You need to create a class, then a method inside that, then put your four lines of code in the method.  You probably need to get a Java tutorial and study a little - otherwise you'll be on here a lot!

Comment: Hehe, thanks but I'm not that green. I choose to omit the class for brevity.